# Selenium + Python - Not able to interact/click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Problem: Not able to find/click/send.keys to any of elements on a specific webpage.

WebDriver Chrome

I can interact with that webpage until I click a certain link where a new tab is opened and from that page I'm unable to do anything.

What I've tried so far after extensive research here:

1- Since a new tab was opened, I've "forced" the code looking into the new tab using **driver.switch_to.window** and to be sure I've printed the current page title and it's the correct one.

2- I've tried both implicit/explicit waiting (even time.sleep) in order to wait for the page to load.

3- Research pointed me to iframe.. I don't have any iframe but nevertheless I've searched for the number of frames (2) and switched between both and tried to find elements using xpath (full xpath) and none were find.

4- Maximize window.

So I tried "everything" in the books. Inspecting the elements that I needed to interact I've found that every single one was pointing to a JS with some arguments.

```
 href="JavaScript:SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm2_0,s_10,"s_2_1_96_0","VRId-0")" tabindex="2997" id="s_2_1_96_0">Track Faults
```

Looking further found that s_10 is a variable within the script which have different options from s_0 to s_14.

```
var s_0 = {action:"/esales_enu/start.swe",target:"_sweview",SWECmd:"GotoView",SWEMethod:"GotoView",SWEView:"L2C Track Channel Reference View BT",SWEApplet:"L2C New CZ Home Page Applet BT",SWEReqRowId:"0",SWESP:"false",SWENeedContext:"true",SWEKeepContext:"0",SWEDIC:"false"};

var s_10 = {action:"/esales_enu/start.swe",target:"_sweview",SWECmd:"GotoView",SWEMethod:"GotoView",SWEView:"New Portal Fault Search View ORH BT",SWEApplet:"L2C New CZ Home Page Applet BT",SWEReqRowId:"0",SWESP:"false",SWENeedContext:"true",SWEKeepContext:"0",SWEDIC:"false"};
```

So I started searching and found **driver.execute_script()** and I've wrote:

```
driver.execute_script("SWESubmitForm(document.SWEForm2_0,s_10,'s_2_1_96_0','VRId-0')")
```

But this occurs:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: SWESubmitForm is not defined
```

What I'm missing here? Syntax? If someone can shed some light on which direction should I go, it will be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this and learn a few things. The JS "theory" I was taking didn't made any sense since the driver.execute_script() isn't used the way I was thinking but rather injecting code or finding elements as well.

Second, the solution was actually frames :)

I was so focused in switching between the two frames I had found initially that for not one moment I thought that INSIDE those two frames could had been more frames!

And basically that was it, after switching to the main frame, I've switched again to the 2nd frame inside that main one and was able to find through xpath.